# What is difference between Neo4jRepository and ReactiveNeo4jRepository?

Tags: database, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-repositories

I am presently building a Spring Boot backend with REST APIs, which is backed by Neo4j Database. So, while going through the official documentations of Spring Data Neo4j I have observed the usage of `ReactiveNeo4jRepository` and `Neo4jRepository` as data repositories for interacting with Database through our program.

**But even going through the limited documentation many times I am unable to figure out how to distinguish among them? Kindly help me make this distinction.**

Comment: reactive is an aysnchronous programming model

Comment: @JimmyGuo Hi, Jimmy! So, are you trying to say that if I implement my data repository with the reactive neo4j repository then it will be thread safe? _If my understanding is correct - then please post it as answer to the question._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Neo4jRepository** and **ReactiveNeo4jRepository** are both interfaces provided by the Spring Data Neo4j project for interacting with Neo4j databases.

**Neo4jRepository** is a standard repository interface for interacting with Neo4j using *blocking I/O*. It provides methods for basic CRUD (create, read, update, delete) operations, as well as methods for executing custom Cypher queries.

On the other hand, **ReactiveNeo4jRepository** is an interface for interacting with Neo4j using *non-blocking reactive I/O*. It extends the Neo4jRepository interface and provides additional methods that return reactive types such as Mono and Flux from the Reactor library, instead of blocking on I/O operations.

So, the main difference between Neo4jRepository and ReactiveNeo4jRepository is the I/O model they use. Neo4jRepository uses blocking I/O, which can lead to performance issues in high-concurrency environments. ReactiveNeo4jRepository, on the other hand, uses non-blocking I/O which can provide better scalability and throughput in such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Linear programming and reactive programming are two different concepts both in their operating logic as well as in the libraries with which the data that is returned from the database is worked with.

In neo4j the reactive interface works with two functions, one to return a single piece of data and another for when the return of a list of data is expected, since they are operated differently.

It is also always advised while technically not prohibited, it is not recommended mixing imperative and reactive database access in the same application.
Regards

**This is the library for the import:**

**Imperative**

Neo4jRepository

org.springframework.data.repository.Repository
org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

**Reactive**

ReactiveNeo4jRepository

org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository
org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveSortingRepository